# Promise not waiting until request is finished

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

I'm trying to chain promises together to make a series of requests. This is one of the few times I've used promises, so I'm not too sure what I'm doing. Hoping that someone can catch whats going on wrong. Basically, my first promise is working correctly, then the second function runs after the first promise is resolved, however, the third does not wait so the information I'm requesting is incomplete.

I can see that my functions are returning the correct information. So mainly my question is how do I format my promises so they each wait for each other to complete before running?

```
function getPaths(folderpath) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    db.getPaths(folderpath, function(response) {
      //get paths for files and folders
      for (let i = 0; i < response.entries.length; i++) {
        let entries = response.entries[i];
        if (entries[".tag"] == "folder") {
          folderPaths.push(response.entries[i].path_lower);
        }
        if (entries[".tag"] == "file") {
          filePaths.push(response.entries[i].path_lower);
        }
      }
      resolve();
    });
  });
}

function openFolders(folders) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    for (let i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
      db.getPaths(folders[i], function(response) {
        for (let j = 0; j < response.entries.length; j++) {
          let entries = response.entries[j];
          if (entries[".tag"] == "file") {
            filePaths.push(response.entries[j].path_lower);
          }
        }
        //console.log(filePaths); //returns correct information
      });
    }
    resolve();
  });
}

getPaths("/path").then(function() {
  openFolders(folderPaths);
}).then(function() {
  console.log(filePaths); //returns incomplete information
});
```

Comment: where is `folderPaths` defined? `folderPaths.push` seems wrong in the async handler- it looks like you're trying to coordinate synchronous code to read from a global var that is modified by asynchronous code -  definitely not the right way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Possibly related: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a big problem  here in **bold**

```
function openFolders(folders) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    for (let i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
      db.getPaths(folders[i], function(response) {
        // ...
      });
    }
    resolve();
  });
}
```

You're running a *synchrounous* `for` loop around an *asynchronous* function call. The loop finishes iterating synchronously and then immediately calls `resolve()` - the code in the async handler (eg, `filePaths.push(...)`) does not run *before* the Promise is resolved

---

Your problems don't stop there though. You're using Promises unconventionally by modifying global state and then resolving and empty Promise - `resolve()` vs `resolve(someValue)`. @FrankModica's answer has more to say about that.

---

As for remedies, I'd recommend you take a look at `Promise.all` - and in general, using Promises in a more conventional way

In the snippet below, I've mocked your `db` function to read from a fake in-memory database, `fakedb`. Then, I made a `getPaths` function which wraps `db.getPaths` but returns a Promise instead. Then I rewrite `openFolders` to create an array of Promises, pass them to `Promise.all`, then finally resolve the values I want

Worth noting: `Promise.all` will run your array of Promises in *parallel* - if this undesirable, you could run them in serial using `.reduce` and `.then`.

```js
const db = {
  getPaths: (path, k) => {
    setTimeout(k, 50, fakedb[path])
  }
}

function getPaths (path) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    db.getPaths(path, response => resolve(response)))
}

function openFolders (folders) {
  return Promise.all(folders.map(getPaths))
    .then(responses =>
      responses.reduce((acc, {entries}) =>
        acc.concat(entries.filter(x => x['.tag'] === 'file').map(x => x.path_lower)), []))
}

const fakedb = {
  'cat': {
    'entries': [
        { '.tag': 'dir', 'path_lower': './cat/.' },
        { '.tag': 'dir', 'path_lower': './cat/..' },
        { '.tag': 'file', 'path_lower': './cat/a' },
        { '.tag': 'file', 'path_lower': './cat/b' },
        { '.tag': 'file', 'path_lower': './cat/c' }
      ]
  },
  'dog': {
    'entries': [
        { '.tag': 'dir', 'path_lower': './dog/.' },
        { '.tag': 'dir', 'path_lower': './dog/..' },
        { '.tag': 'file', 'path_lower': './dog/a' },
        { '.tag': 'file', 'path_lower': './dog/b' },
        { '.tag': 'file', 'path_lower': './dog/c' }
      ]
  }
}

openFolders(['cat','dog']).then(console.log, console.error)
```

The operation I'm performing in `openFolders` might feel a little complex because it handles all transformations of the `responses` in a single `.then` handler - you could (**optionally**) separate the work into multiple `.then` calls which might result in a lighter cognitive load

```
function openFolders (folders) {
  return Promise.all(folders.map(getPaths))
    // get `.entries` of each response
    .then(responses =>
      responses.map(x => x.entries))
    // flatten array of entries arrays into a single array
    .then(arrOfEntries =>
      arrOfEntries.reduce((acc, entries) =>
        acc.concat(entries), []))
    // only keep entries where `.tag` of each entry is `'file'`
    .then(entries =>
      entries.filter(x => x['.tag'] === 'file'))
    // return `path_lower` of the resulting entries
    .then(entries =>
      entries.map(x => x.path_lower))
}
```

Comment: How do you know db.getPaths is asynchronous? It is not the same function that he is declaring.

Comment: How would I go about running getPaths for each item in folders? If I were to uncommented the print statement in that function, the correct information is in fact being added?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you're response

Comment: I didn't notice the potentially async call inside the loop. Can you update your answer with a way to fix it?

Comment: @NickWyman I don't *know*, I just strongly inferred it based on the function name being prefixed with `db` and the signature continuation passing style (callback)

Comment: @23k it was a bit of a challenge, but I was able to create a runnable code snippet in my updated answer. I think you'll be happy with the results.

Comment: @FrankModica the updated answer offers *one* possible way it could be done

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you are using some variables from the outer scope (`folderPaths` and `filePaths`). I'm not sure that's the best way to go about this, but I believe it will start working once you return the promise from `openFolders`. This way you wait until `openFolders` completes:

```
getPaths("/path").then(function() {
  return openFolders(folderPaths);
}).then(function() {
  console.log(filePaths);
});
```

But I'd recommend resolving the information required for the next call:

```
resolve(folderPaths);
```

And:

```
resolve(filePaths);
```

So your code can look more like:

```
getPaths("/path").then(function(folderPaths) {
  return openFolders(folderPaths);
}).then(function(filePaths) {
  console.log(filePaths); 
});
```

**Edit:** Looks like you may have another issue mentioned by @naomik. If `db.getPaths` is async, in your `openFolders` function you may be resolving before all of the async calls in the loop complete. Unfortunately I don't have time right now to show the solution. Hopefully @naomik can!